# do we need to deploy war after changing property file

Tags: java

Do we need to deploy war after changing the property file in java?

Comment: if nothing changes... probably yes :)

Comment: Only if you want the changes to be deployed and become effective.

Comment: ya changes need to be reflected... that means i would need to deploy war again?

Answer (score 1):

At least you may have to restart the application so that it reads the new property file. So re-deploying the entire application may not be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

you do need war to deploy if property file is not loaded each time it is needed

Answer (score -1):

Yes, unless you make your context reloadable. To do that update your conf/context.xml, adding the "reloadable" attribute to the root node like so:

```
<Context reloadable="true">
```

Take a look at the [Tomcat Config Docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/context.html).